# Separate same jars in different WAR of a EAR

Tags: ant, jakarta-ee, jar, war, ear

currently we are facing one problem. We are building a ear which contains multiple war files. In 2 of the WARs contains same jars. Both these wars need these jars during deployment.So Is there any way in ANT I can built it so that these jars will be in one single place and it will not create any problem during the ear deployment.

Comment: Which version of which application server?

Answer (score 1):

well, you can do it the portable way:

Place the library jars at the root of .ear file.
Example:

```
library jar -> lib1.jar, lib2.jar

[EAR STRUCTURE]
your.ear
|--yourfirst.war
|--yoursecond.war
|--lib1.jar
|--lib2.jar
```

Update the MANIFEST.MF files in *both* the .war files to point to these jars
like so:
`Class-Path: lib1.jar lib2.jar`
(dont forget to add a space and a newline character to the end of the above line if this is the last entry in the manifest)

Answer (score 0):

You can put those shared JARs into the EAR's `lib` directory. Those will then be available on the classpath for any WARs in that EAR.

Comment: Many Thanks skaffman...I will try this and come back to you if found some issue.