# communicate between wars and jar inside ear

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

I'm new to creating ear and communicaton between wars and jar...

I was having two wars having completely independent functionality.
Now I've to create a Ear, where two application have to work on same functionality,
which is enclosed in a jar.But requirement is I must not include the jar in Pom.xml of both but make use of that jar, where all 3 are under single ear.is this is possible? 
      I've tested Ear with 2 independent wars and it's working fine now how to achieve above I'm not getting this.
        I'm using Maven with Jboss7.1.1.
    I went through links like [MessageHandler in JAR/WAR/EAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420320/messagehandler-in-jar-war-ear) , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796255/tell-me-a-clear-differnece-between-ear-war-and-jar but got no idea about above problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hi got the solution >> here it is.. this is a pom.xml of ear project


<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging> 

<dependencies>
    <!--Dependency for jar-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jar</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.jar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <!--Dependency for war1-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.war2</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.war2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>       
    <!--Dependency for war2-->  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.war1</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.war1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>Project</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>MyEarFile</finalName>
                <version>5</version>
                <modules>
                    <!--Webmodule for war1-->
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.war1</groupId>
                        <artifactId>com.war1</artifactId>
                        <uri>war1.war</uri>
                        <bundleFileName>war1.war</bundleFileName>
                    </webModule>

                    <!--Webmodule for war2-->
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.war2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>com.war2</artifactId>
                        <uri>war2.war</uri>
                        <bundleFileName>war2.war</bundleFileName>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>




Note:: groupId and artifactId metioned here must match with groupId and artifactId mentioned in the project's pom.xml.
Also dependency of jar must be present in this i.e. ear's pom.xml and not in both app's pom.xml.
At time of maven install it automatically refers to jar's contents..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple wars and jars into a ear and they can share the same classloader. This means that all the classes are accessible from all the jars/wars. i.e. it is as if all the classes / resouces are in one archive without the sub-packaging.

I am assuming this is what you mean by "communication between wars and jars".

EDIT: check [Making an EAR with Maven](http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/Making+an+EAR+with+Maven#MakinganEARwithMaven-EARModule) for an example of the pom.xml for building an ear. In the example, there is one jar and one war but you could have any number of wars / jars.

Comment: Thanks for you reply I'm new to this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337784/separate-same-jars-in-different-war-of-a-ear  I want something like this i.e. same jar accessed by two apps. but I'm not getting how to make this work using 'maven'.

Comment: Also once dependency of applications, is removed from pom.xml then it won't create wars then how to create war by giving reference of jar from ear?

Comment: If I understand your questions, then you just reference the jars/wars in the pom which builds the ear.

Comment: yes.See I want to buid an ear which will have 3 components singel jar and 2 wars , which will reduce code duplication as both wants to refer same jar ,so how I should do it? Can you please elaborate with an example showing pom.xml.

Comment: hi  drone.ah , same I got after working on it.. Thanks for your help  also :) :)