# accessing same hibernate.cfg.xml in two applications

Tags: hibernate, maven, ear

I have webapplications with maven and hibernate.

I have 2 wars and a jar which contains common database code including getting sessionfactory.

I use ear in which all above 3 are webmodules. At runtime both war accesses the jar.
I'm able to access this database code in one war which contains hibernate.cfg.xml.
What will be feasible solution to access database code in other war?
Should I keep hibernate.cfg.xml also in jar so that both project can access it or any other way to do this?

Ear structure is some what like right answer under this  [communicate between wars and jar inside ear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909213/communicate-between-wars-and-jar-inside-ear)

Answer (score 2):

The `hibernate.cfg.xml` should be neither in a jar nor in an ear file but in the "normal" file system. This configuration file contains the access to the specific data base (for example user, password, name ant port). These data should not be included in a delivery. They might be changed by an administrator (for example new password).

Comment: While I do agree with you, I also disagree. You can have Maven profiles to do this setup for you per server.

Comment: Johanna and carlspring thanks for your relies I'll go through this and check for solution.

Comment: Hello Johanna,I've modified jar,and while accesing session factory I've used static variable named 'path' which has path to access hibernate.cfg.xml.At the time of wars deployment this value is assigned to this variable.But again while accessing this session factory from war which is initialising this path variable is working fine and other war is throwing null pointer exception.How should I make this work?

Comment: When Hibernate can't find or access the configuration file, then you do _not_ get a null pointer exception. You'd get a different exception. There must be an other error in your code.